# Trying to understand GUI Swing and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingbuilder

I have the following application. It works, I am just trying to understand it better.
So from the main class I make the following call

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 Gui gui = new Gui();
 gui.startGui();    
}
```

In the GUI Class

```
public Gui() 
{   
 initialize();
}

private void initialize() 
{
 mainWinFrm = new JFrame();
 mainWinFrm.setTitle("Inventory Tool");

 JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
 mainWinFrm.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
 .....//allot more GUI staff getting initialize
 }

public void startGui() 
{
  try {UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());} 
  catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {}
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
  {
    public void run()
    {
      try 
      {
        Gui window = new Gui();
        window.mainWinFrm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.mainWinFrm.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        window.mainWinFrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.mainWinFrm.pack();
        window.mainWinFrm.setVisible(true);             
       } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {e.printStackTrace();} 
   }
 });
}
```

The structure of the above code was build by a GUI builder and I guess I am trying to understand whats happening.

The main point that i dont understand is when we construct the object **gui** in main class it initializes all the variables and then it starts the thread **gui.startGui()** that method also creates a new GUI object window and initialize all the variables.

This doesn't seem right to me ... but then I am not sure if i am missing something.

Thanks for the advice/help
Alexis

Comment: Take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Having the initialize method and startGui method makes no sense. The startGui method is the correct approach for starting a Swing UI

Comment: It doesn't seem right - a `Gui` object is created twice: first in `main` and again in `startGui`. Perhaps `startGui` should be declared `static` and called as `Gui.startGui()`. What tool built this code?

Comment: Actually, if you remove the construction of of the GUI in the startGui method, then it makes better sense...(remove Gui window = new Gui();)

Comment: The GUI should also be *created* in the EDT (there are lots of old advice lying around that does not follow that, but the recommendation has changed), so it's the best to just wrap everything in `main()` with `invokeLater().`

Comment: guys thanks for the help! @MadProgrammer what you suggested now makes sense. Its allot more clear to me whats happening, but dont think there is a way to accept your comment as teh answer

Comment: @Joni i am using [WindowBuilder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/) in eclipse, but i am sure its my fault it generated this code :-)

Comment: @alexis No longer on the iPad, so I've expanded my comments into an answer, have a look over it a let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @alexis While use Netbeans form designer on regular bases, I highly recommend that you hand code all your UI's until you have a firm understanding of what you are doing.  WindowsBuilder is nutritious for not following the rules ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

The `Gui` class is a little awkward...but's not far from being workable...

In the `initialize` it is creating the basics of the UI, in the `startUI` it is switching over to the Event Dispatching Thread, making a new instance of `Gui` and showing the main frame...

The part that is weird is the creation of the second instance of `Gui` in the `startUI`.  Instead, you could do something like...

```
public Gui() 
{   
    // It's arguable, but I'm paranoid, so I prefer to do anything related
    // to the UI within the EDT...
}

private void initialize() 
{
    mainWinFrm = new JFrame();
    mainWinFrm.setTitle("Inventory Tool");

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    mainWinFrm.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    .....//allot more GUI staff getting initialize
}

public void startGui() 
{
    try {UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());} 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {}
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try 
            {
                // Initialize here instead...
                initialize();
                window.mainWinFrm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.mainWinFrm.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
                window.mainWinFrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.mainWinFrm.pack();
                window.mainWinFrm.setVisible(true);             
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
                {e.printStackTrace();} 
        }
    });
}
```

This still doesn't sit right with, because now it's possible to access parts of the class before they've being initalised, instead, I would prefer to doing something more like...

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // Initialise the system look and feel...
            try 
            {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) 
            {
            }
            Gui window = new Gui();
            window.mainWinFrm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.mainWinFrm.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
            window.mainWinFrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.mainWinFrm.pack();
            window.mainWinFrm.setVisible(true);             
        }
    });
}

public Gui() 
{   
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() 
{
    mainWinFrm = new JFrame();
    mainWinFrm.setTitle("Inventory Tool");

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    mainWinFrm.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    .....//allot more GUI staff getting initialize
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better Approach :
Gui Class :

```
public class Gui {
private JFrame mainWinFrm;

public Gui() {
    initialize();

}

private void initialize() {
    mainWinFrm = new JFrame();
    mainWinFrm.setTitle("Inventory Tool");

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    mainWinFrm.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

}

public static void startGui() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    try {

        Gui window = new Gui();
        window.mainWinFrm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.mainWinFrm.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        window.mainWinFrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.mainWinFrm.pack();
        window.mainWinFrm.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And MainClass :

```
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 Gui.startGui();
}
```

}

It is better way as it is not creating any extra object.

Comment: I might be tempted to make the constructor `protected` to prevent any body from accidently creating an instance of the class

Comment: well, It is just a hint, Not the final code. Developer should always use preventive measures to make the code efficient and robust